# in which directory should i place my .php file

Tags: php

My OS is windows xp.

I have installed apache HTTP Server 2.2

I have installed PHP 5.

I am not able to execute my .php file.

I am new to php. i have written my first .php file.

But i do not know in which directory to place my .php file as there is no web directory folder in apache HTTP Server 2.2

Regards,
Ashish

Answer (score 2):

If this is your first time setting up a local server, then I would suggest using a package like [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

However, moving on to your question. You will need to locate `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation` and follow this from the Apache guide:

> After installing Apache, you must edit
>   the configuration files in the conf
>   subdirectory as required. These files
>   will be configured during the
>   installation so that Apache is ready
>   to be run from the directory it was
>   installed into, with the documents
>   server from the subdirectory **htdocs**.

Comment: `+1` The use of WAMP or XAMPP makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be somewhere within your document root.  In your apache httpd.conf, locate DOCUMENT_ROOT, then place your file in that directory.  You may also need to ensure that the web server has execute permission on your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder inside the httpdocs folder. This is the default web root directory.